# Drupal custom fivestar widget

Tags: drupal, drupal-fivestar

I want to have a custom widget for fivestar ratings that shows the average votes in following form

[image]

Does anyone have any ideas or knows of any already present widget that shows average vote in the above format.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look here for [creating your own custom fivestar widget](http://www.drupalace.com/page_drupal_tutorial_make_custom_fivestar_graphics).  Check out the comment of Bleen on making your own helper module, to avoid hacking the fivestar module itself (so when you update the module, you don't have to re-insert your code in the new version).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Content Completion Module](http://drupal.org/project/content_complete). You might be able to modify it to read from the votingapi.